# Live pull data from database in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I pull data in real time from a MySQL database via Laravel?

I'd prefer to call the code from a blade view.

How can I implement this, or what's the right approach for this?

The line of code I'm using to get the data is:

```
Facility::where('aID',$this->id)->where('type',$type)->count();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I'm sure you're aware, with pure PHP you won't be able to do this.

If you're open to "live" meaning, periodically every second or so, you could do this with a recurring ajax call with jQuery which would do a recount, and replace the current count with the new value.

It will mean also, that you won't be able to do this from a single blade view, you're going to need to setup a controller to be able to do your ajax call to which will return you the new count.

#### Main blade view

```
<h1>
  The current count is 
  <span id="mycount">
    {{ Facility::where('aID',$this->id)->where('type',$type)->count(); }}
  </span>
</h1>
```

#### jQuery

```
function getCount() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "{{ route('route_for_new_data_here') }}"
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
      $('#mycount').html(data);

      setTimeout(getCount, 1000);
    });
}
getCount();
```

#### Controller

In a controller, you'll need something then to work with this and send back the count

```
function getCount()
{
    echo Facility::where('aID',$this->id)->where('type',$type)->count();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me clue how to do it :D i wrote a controller and try to make the function. but the function see not working :( the URL can actually return the count. may i know why? thanks

Comment: you need to make it just like you would any other page, but instead of displaying content you display the value.

Comment: sorry... I think I should have being `echo`ing the result, not `return`ing... answer updated.

Comment: yea. echo but also not updated. this is the js code. http://paste.laravel.com/1jjn and i tried to call up the URL. it does returning the count

Comment: argh, again... my apologies, the second `setTimeout` call shouldn't be in the function... answer updated

Comment: finally i make it working :D this one setTimeout(function(){getCount()}, 1000);

Comment: sloppy of me, sorry... `getCount` shouldn't have been in quotes. Answer updated for hopefully the last time!